# Get state from select form in child component with Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I code a Gatsby app with a Main page and two components. The value from a select form will be used to query a Postgresql database through a graphql query.

**What I can already do:** in the form component, I get the value from the select menu and pass it from this child component to the parent (the main page). In the data component, I can query the database with graphql and get the results with hardcoded values.

**What I can't do yet:** get the value from the select component to the data component and use it in my graphql query.

I tried different ways to get the value without success using this.props.value1 or this.state.value1. I also tested a simple component to make sure I could get the value from the parent to a child component and it worked seamlessly. So it's the way I try to import the value in a querying component that is the problem.

```
**//Data component**
let val = 88 //for hardcoded test. That works.

const DataPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>From Postgres: {data.postgres.allEstivalsList[val].nbr}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const query = graphql`
{
  postgres {
    allAveragesList {
     avg
    }
     allEstivalsList {
      year
      nbr
    }
  }
}
`;

export default DataPage; 

**//Main page**
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    value1: null,
    // other values
  }

  render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>Get state in main page: {this.state.value1}</p>
            <DataPage val = {this.state.value1} />
            <SelectForm clickHandler={y => { this.setState({ value1: y }); }} />
          </div>
        )
    }
}

**//Form component**

export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value1: null,
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.clickHandler(this.state.value1);

    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { value1: prevState.value1 };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Formlayout>                                    
      <p>Test -- Value for the selected year: {this.state.value1}</p>
      <select onChange = {(e) => this.setState({ value1: e.target.value })}>
      <option value="">-- Year --</option>
      <option value="1">1901</option>
      <option value="2">1902</option>
      <option value="3">1903</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Go!</button>
      </Formlayout>
    )
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate to get some directions to get the select value in the data component. As my test variable val is effectively working when used in the query, what I'd like to achieve is to apply to that variable the state from  the component. And that's where I'm stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

The GraphQL query is executed at the build time, not at runtime. Have a look at the docs, it's possible to query data at build and at runtime.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-data-fetching/

// edit

Normally you would pre generate all (static) content pages - e.g. if you have data for 50 years, you let gatsby build those 50 pages and then you could navigate by path to the page.

If you want to pass a variable to the query, check the docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#query-variables

```
query GetBlogPosts(
  $limit: Int, $filter: MarkdownRemarkFilterInput, $sort: MarkdownRemarkSortInput
) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
    limit: $limit,
    filter: $filter,
    sort: $sort
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
          date(formatString: "dddd DD MMMM YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. But what I'd like to find at first is a way to get the *this.props.value1* in that component and then use it in the query. It's straightforward in a class but here I can't find the right way.

Comment: I only used graphql with gatsby at build time, not at run time. In your case I'd expect that you have some kind of graphql or rest interface to fetch data from. Also it would help if you name the props by purpose. E.g. year instead if "value1" :)

Comment: Naming: true, I'll change that.
Static: here I have 150 years for multiple location so maybe generating all pages may be a bit too of a load
Variable: well, I tested with a test hardcoded variable in the query (the Data part of my code above and that works perfectly.
What I miss is to catch the value coming from the parent and affect it to this variable. I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Well, that is how gatsby is supposed to work! Pre-generate all content so that no database calls are involved and deliver as much as pre rendered HTML as possible.  I'm maintaining a page that has like 1000+ generated pages and if somebody makes an update, we simply redeploy the whole thing